# Why doesn't ::1 match 127.0.0.1?

Tags: ip, ipv6, network-protocols, loopback, ipv4

The loopback IP address in IPv6 format is:
0000:0000: **0000:0000**: 0000:0000: **0000:0001**

which is shortened to:
0:0: **0:0**: 0:0: **0:1**

which is then shortened to (keep last 2 words, ie. 4 bytes, to match IPv4):
**:0:1** (But I still don't know why it's double colons instead of single colon before 1, maybe for implying that there are 4 bytes here)

and simplified as:
**::1**

Expand ::1 into IPv4 format, it is:
**0.0.0.1**

But this is not the same as **127.0.0.1**, where's the number 127?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `:0:1` is not a valid IPv6 address. I'll explain why:

IPv6 address are 128 bit addresses written as eight hexadecimal parts separated by colons. Because this can be quite tedious to write, and because many IPv6 address (like `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`) contain many parts that are zero, it's allowed to replace one sequence of zeroes with two colons. The full address is still the same. It's just easier to write `::` than `0:0:0:etc`.

IPv4 and IPv6 are two different protocols. You cannot compare the IPv4 loopback address `127.0.0.1` with the IPv6 loopback address `::1`. They are completely unrelated. Both of them just happen to end with the same digit.

Comment: Yes, they are so unrelated that the IPv4 loopback is really an entire network (`127.0.0.0/8`), and the IPv6 loopback is a single address. This has has created problems for some programmers who have relied on using multiple loopback addresses for IPv4 when they are trying to convert an application to IPv6.